# ETL Matching Code Page SSIS Data Flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, codepages

I have found plenty online, but nothing specific to my problem.  I have a CSV rendered in code page 65001 (Unicode).  However, in the Advanced section of the Flat File Connection Manager, the column is data type `string [DT_STR]`

My database table I am loading to can be in any format; I don't care.  My question is what is the best way to handle this?

1) Change the Advanced properties of the flat file connection columns?
2) Change the data types of the SQL table to NVARCHAR?
3) Change the OLE DB properties to AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage = TRUE?
4) Use Data Conversion task to convert the column data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source's code page doesn't change, my suggestion is to use a simple data conversion, try to avoid manipulating source and destination whenever possible. Always go for ETL solutions first.

Answer (score 0):

I usually always start off with setting up my connection string for the flat file, then converting the data using a data conversion component (input/output datatypes) based on the flat file data types and destination datatypes. Then finally setting up the connection string for the DB destination. Below is an example of how my data flow looks.

[image: Flat File to Database]